# How to get access to the user's Google Tasks from android app?

Tags: android, task

Does anybody have completed source code of the synching with Google tasks? 
I have some problem with the authorization

Answer (score -1):

You have to get a key from ur google account and then use that key for authorisation.

Comment: I got clientID and clientSecret. But how to get access to google tasks using these values and user's e-mail/password?